# Send message to LINE app by scheme

Tags: android, android-intent, line

I could use scheme supported by LINE app to share messages.

But the problem is when the LINE app is not launched at first by user and the share from my app could work perfectly only once.

After user presses the send button in LINE app and shared message, just back to my app. From the second time, the LINE app is only showed from back to front and the message get lost.

I have tried to set different intent flags, but all of them do not work at all.

My question is, are there flags could make the LINE app work, just like the first time share even from the second time.

Here is the part how I share message to LINE app.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(lineString));
for (int flag : flags) {
    intent.setFlags(flag);
}
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: So the sharing only worked at the first attempt?

Comment: Yes, only the first time the connector choose activity will be showed. From second time that activity will never show.